# Java splash command line used in javafx build.xml not working

Tags: java, javafx, build.xml, splash-screen

I read the Oracle doc [How to Create a Splash Screen](http://How%20to%20Create%20a%20Splash%20Screen),follow the guide, I can make my javafx application show a splash before preloader start on java -jar command.

Then, I add a jvmarg to fx:Platform of fx:depoly in the build.xml file,the jvmarg was `<fx:jvmarg value="-splash:res/img/logo.png"/>`, hopely ,I want to show the splash before application preloader start when I launch the application through myApplication.exe that build by fx:deploy , but ,it seems not working.

I also tried with add `<attribute name="SplashScreen-Image" value="res/img/logo.png"/>` param to mainfest.mf ,when I launched the application in command line it worked,but when I launched the application through myApplication.exe that build by fx:deploy didn't work again.

So, it's there a way to show the splash screen before javafx preloader start when launch the applcation by myApplication.exe but not through command line?

Below is part of build.xml:

```
<fx:deploy width="${javafx.run.width}" height="${javafx.run.height}" includeDT="${javafx.deploy.includeDT}" nativeBundles="all" outdir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" embedJNLP="${javafx.deploy.embedJNLP}" outfile="${application.title}" verbose="true">
        <fx:application
                name="${application.title}"
                mainClass="${javafx.main.class}"/>
        <fx:resources>
            <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
            <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="libs/*"/>
        </fx:resources>

        <fx:platform>
            <fx:jvmarg value="-Xmx512m"/>
            <fx:jvmarg value="-splash:res/img/logo.png"/>
            <!--<fx:jvmarg value="-verbose:jni"/>
            <property name="my.property" value="something"/>-->
        </fx:platform>


        <fx:preferences install="false"/>
        <info title="${application.title}"
              vendor="${application.vendor}"/>
    </fx:deploy>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does your .jar file actually contain a `res/img/logo.png` entry?  (Every .jar file is actually a zip file, so if you can't view the contents of the .jar in an IDE, copy the file, rename the copy to have a .zip extension, and examine its contents.)

Comment: yes,my .jar file contain the logo file.

Comment: I found the following open issues https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087431 and https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091654