# Have three equally sized VBoxes in HBox in javafx

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have three VBoxes in a HBox. I want all of them to always take one third of the HBox and the full height. I've tried `HBox.setHgrow(<every VBox>, Priority.ALWAYS)` with `<every VBox>.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);` and that worked fine, but when I added a component to one of the VBoxes, it resized itself and became larger than the other ones.

Any idea how to solve this properly?

Comment: Do you have to use that structure for some reason? Placing the `VBox`es in a `GridPane` and setting `columnConstraint`s would make this very easy.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that makes more sense. I've set up 3 `columnConstraint`s and added my VBoxes. How do I get them to always take the full height and one third of the width now? They don't seem to expand without content.

Comment: Nevermind, made it thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't a TilePane be even easier?

Comment: @James_D   can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37041571/java-splash-command-line-used-in-javafx-build-xml-not-working  question? I can not find a better way to contact with you, sorry everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `GridPane` instead of the `HBox`. You can use a collection of column constraints, each with the `percentWidth` set to give each column equal width.

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class VBoxInGridPane extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox box1 = new VBox();
        box1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: -fx-background; -fx-background: red ;");
        box1.getChildren().add(new Label("Content"));
        VBox box2 = new VBox();
        box2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green ;");
        VBox box3 = new VBox();
        box3.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue ;");

        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.add(box1, 0, 0);
        root.add(box2, 1, 0);
        root.add(box3, 2, 0);

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++) {
            ColumnConstraints cc = new ColumnConstraints();
            cc.setPercentWidth(100.0/3.0);
            cc.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
            root.getColumnConstraints().add(cc);
        }

        RowConstraints rc = new RowConstraints();
        rc.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
        root.getRowConstraints().add(rc);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to add your `VBox` to a `StackPane` and the `StackPane` to the `HBox`. Into the `StackPane` you also place a placeholder (I usually use a transparent `Rectangular`) and bind that to the binding `maxVBoxWidth`. This is a `Binding` that you have to define yourself:

```
   DoubleBinding maxVBoxBinding = new DoubleBinding() {
        {
            super.bind(vbox1.widthProperty(),vbox2.widthProperty(), vbox3.widthProperty());
        }
        @Override
        protected double computeValue() {
            return Math.max(vbox1.getWidth(), Math.max(vbox2.getWidth(), vbox2.getWidth()));
        }
    }
```